# After deploying a Github page, how do you update it with changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I've deployed a project as a Github Page using `npm run deploy`. Now, I have made new changes to my project on my `master` branch and pushed them to the remote `master` branch. However, doing so does not seem to update my Github Page. What step(s) am I missing? Do I need to re-run `npm run deploy`?

Comment: Did you compile the React code to static pages before commiting and pushing?

Comment: @Samathingamajig The first time I deployed, I ran `npm run deploy` first, then pushed to `master`. When I wanted to update my page with new changes, I just pushed those changes to `master`. I did not try running `npm run deploy` again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After pushing your code to master branch, run `npm run deploy`. This will make a new commit and push to your gh-pages branch that your GitHub Pages app running on. Then refresh your page. If you don't see any changes, wait a couple minutes and refresh it again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced some issues and found out recently. Yes, you need to deploy it again by *npm run deply*
However, there is "Page not found" issue when you refresh the file you updated.

- In this case, I deleted the gh-pages branch in Github and deployed again. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

All what you need is to run `npm run deploy`, you can customize that in your `package.json` under the `scripts` tag, this is will update your github page brunch with the last updates

Answer (score -1):

As I'm not sure on which step you messed up I will provide you with steps from the beginning which I follow and everything works perfectly fine.

1. Create a repository for your app.

run:

```
npm init react-app appname
```

2. Install GitHub Pages package

I use this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages and afterwards:
run:

```
cd appname
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

3. Modify your repos `package.json` file

add/change homepage per your names:

```
"homepage": "http://yourUserName.github.io/appname"
```

also to the scripts section add:

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

4. Create a remote GitHub repository and initialize it

run:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:yourUserName/appname.git
```

5. deploy it to gh-pages.

run:

```
npm run deploy
```

6. Commit and push your changes

run:

```
git commit -m "commit description"
git push origin master
```

If something wouldn't work or you would have issues with some step - please leave a comment and I will try to help you

Comment: Thanks for the overview, but my question is what happens after I have run through the steps you've outlined and I want to make subsequent changes to my app. I work on my `master` branch, so would I simply push changes there as I usually do? And does my Github Page update automatically? Or do I need to run `npm run deploy` as well as push to my `master` branch every time I want to update my Github Page?

Comment: That helped in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63698242/13017141